# MY DOMAIN RESOLVING ON LOCALHOST BUT NOT ON INTERNET

Tags: dns

I have a virtual machine which has Vmware bridged network card and Windows Server 2008 R2 x86.
I created a forest DNS Server with Active Domain Directory.

I have web server and dns server on the same machine. Domain name is resolving in local machine and IIS is properly displaying my web site.
Is that a problem dns server and web server on the same machine? (I think it shouldn't be, because of having different port numbers)

I forwarded following ports on my router: 80,443,53.

What can i do to see my domain on internet?

Comment: I don't understand what isn't unclear actually. My question is how does public domain servers know my domain name? daskwuff said i have to purchase domain name from suppliers. So, how the suppliers distribute domain names to internet? Why can't i distribute myself?

Answer (score 2):

Setting up a DNS server does not will a domain into existence. You have to purchase a domain name through a registrar and configure it appropriately before it will work on the Internet.

Comment: http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/creating/domainathome.html